# Applescript: Copy files from CSV to single folder

Tags: csv, file, copy, applescript

I have a CSV list of files that I'm trying to copy from a server onto a folder on my desktop.

Examples of the filenames in the CSV are

- Volumes:imagetree:Approved:All_languages:Image_Hierarchy:00800-00899:00877x3.jpg
- Volumes:imagetree:Approved:All_languages:Image_Hierarchy:47600-47699:47676x3.jpg

The script I tried is:

```
tell application "Finder"
set textFile to "Users:jrosario:Desktop:5221:" & "FamilyDealImageroot.csv"
set readText to read alias textFile
set myFolder to "Users:jrosario:Desktop:5221"
repeat with listFiles in paragraphs of readText as alias
    copy alias listFiles to folder myFolder
end repeat
end tell
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: It would really help if you revealed what happened rather than it's `not working`. Are you getting an error? If so what and where? By the way, have you installed the Satimage (Smile) scripting addition? You can't casually use `readText` as a variable if you have. And what OS version are you running? And does your csv file contain only the file path/name (i.e. no spaces, no tabs, no anything)?

Answer (score 0):

This may work. It does for me in Sierra.

```
set keyFolder to (path to desktop) & "5221:" as text
set textFile to keyFolder & "FamilyDealImageroot.csv" as text
set readtext1 to read file textFile

tell application "Finder"
    
    repeat with eachFile in paragraphs of readtext1
        duplicate eachFile as alias to keyFolder with replacing
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

You could also append the first two lines with `as alias` and remove `file` from the third line. There are different ways to refer to files. Ideally, the file references in the text file would include the name of the volume (before 'Users:'). The applescript command for 'copying' a file is actually 'duplicate'.

As an aside, I can't help but imagine that the question of moving/copying files based on a list in a file has been asked and answered here before.